# How to get logs from a lambda trigger in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Some time ago, I developed a lambda function, this function has s3 bucket as trigger. The event type is s3:ObjectCreated:* and the suffix is .csv. Everything was working fine.

For a few days I see that when I upload a csv the trigger no longer works. Nothing was changed, which is why I want to see the logs for a lambda trigger.

It's possible?
I need to see why the lambda trigger is not working, I don't know if there are any logs or error messages from the lambda triggers.

I was reading a lot of literature and I can't find something like what I need. Cloudwatch only shows logs for lambdas and obviously if a lambda doesn't start then no logs are logged and I can't see why the trigger didn't start.

Comment: No, there is no logs for the trigger. Maybe you can post the details of your set up including the S3 Event notification settings of the bucket and the resource policy of your lambda function that's supposed to get triggered. We can go from there.

Comment: Further:  Have you looked for logs?  It's entirely possible something is causing the Lambda to fail.